# Denotation - Logic

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, model-theory

I am currently studying the proof of the undecidability of dyadic logic from the book Computability and Logic (see section 21.3), written by George S. Boolos and John P. Burgess. I came across the notion of 'denotation' but I do not know what this means. See the following fragment of the proof:
[image]

Could someone please explain this to me?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Denotation=reference. The object for which a name stand for.

Comment: The name "Napoleon" denotes/refers to the emperor Napeon.

Comment: In logic the *denotation* of an unary predicate is a subset of the domain of the interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what the paragraph above means.

Dyadic logic in *Computability and Logic* has only two-place predicates and does not have $=$.

In the chapter 12, where the canonical domains theorem is introduced (I can't find the theorem itself, 12.18 appears to be an exercise (?)), we have the [Löwenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem). Additionally, without $=$, we can't restrict the size of our domain to be finite.

These two facts together give us the ability to build a new model $M'$ whose domain is $\mathbb{N}$ given a model $M$ over any domain. $M'$ and $M$ are [elementarily equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_equivalence).

A denotation is an object in the domain, or an element of some larger set built using the domain, that gives a symbol its meaning.

If $x$ is a constant or a variable, the denotation of $x$ in $(M, \vec{v})$ is an element of the domain of $M$. $x$'s denotation is provided by $M$ if and only if $x$ is a constant. $x$'s denotation is provided by $\vec{v}$ if and only if $x$ is a variable.

If $x$ is an $n$-ary predicate, then the denotation of $x$ is an element of $2^{M^n}$, where $2^A$ denotes the [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of $A$ and $M^n$ denotes the  [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the domain of $M$ with itself $n$ times.

If $x$ is an $n$-ary function, then the denotation of $x$ is the denotation of the $n{+}1$-ary relation corresponding to the [graph of the function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoforest#Graphs_of_functions).

The second part of the paragraph is describing a procedure for taking a ternary predicate $P$ in the original model $\mathcal{M}$ and paraphrasing it away using binary relations only.

$P(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ is a well-formed formula in $\mathcal{M}$ headed by a ternary predicate.

$\exists w \mathop. Q_1(w, x_1) \land Q_2(w, x_2) \land Q_3(w, x_3) \land P^*(w)$ is a paraphrase in $\mathcal{M}^*$. In this case, $w$ is a number and the set of all values of $w$ that satisfy $P^*(w)$ plays a role similar to the graph of $P$. $Q_1$, $Q_2$, and $Q_3$ give us the ability to ask whether specific numbers in our domain are specific places within the triple $w$. For example $Q_2((3, 4, 5), 4)$ is true, but $Q_2((3, 4, 5), 3)$ is false.

Comment: What is meant with the sentence "to take as the denotation of P* in M* the relation that holdsof a number b if and only if f(b) is a triple a1, a2, a3 for which the relation that is the denotation of P in M holds"

This sentence really confuses me

Comment: @Mikalo So, $f$ is in some sense "backwards". It is a map from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. What it does is "unpack" an encoded triple into its constituent parts. For example, we could devise an encoding where $f(11\,03\,11\,04\,11\,05) = (3, 4, 5)$ where $11$ starts a new entry, $0X$ indicates the digit $X$ as a payload, and spaces are added only for legibility. $f$ would then be an [interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(model_theory)).